# Problem writing literal ' "\n" ' to a document file in python 3.7

Tags: python, escaping, newline, literals

and thank you for reading. I am currently struggling with a seemingly simple problem in Python 3.7 that is driving me nuts. Similar topics in this forum yielded no working solution for me.

I have a document with following structure:

```
line1

line2 

line3
```

That I have to parse to a format like:

```
"line1\n"

"line2\n"
```

etc.

Sadly, while I can get the changed lines to display correctly on the terminal using repr('\n"') or ('//n'"), whenever I try to write the output to file using .write() or redirect with >>, there is an additional newline added at the position of the \n, despite repr, // or r, so the output that ends up in the file looks like:

"line
\n"

The codeline in question would be:
'''
'"' + str(line) + '//n"' #or + repr('/n"')
'''
I also tried:
'''
'"' `+ str(line) + '//n'.replace('//n', '/n')`
''' 
on suggestion of another user.

r"/n" seems to do nothing at all. Any suggestions would be welcome, as well as suggestions on how to tackle this problem in shell.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood, you want to retain new lines in the output file + have \n added to the end of each line. See if below works for you.

```
with open('source.txt') as f:
    list_ = [(line.strip() + r'\n') for line in f if line != '\n']

print(list_)

with open('output.txt', 'w') as wb_file:
    wb_file.write('\n\n'.join(list_))
```

list_ is conscturcted using list comprehension. adding fake '\n' to the end of each read line.

when writing to the file, I used join with 2 additional \n as your output was with newlines retained. you can remove, and leave one \n if you don't want new lines in the output.

Comment: This adds a curious empty line between all lines, buuuut these can be easily removed using grep. This is really good. Thank you!

Comment: no need for grep actually, just have this `wb_file.write('\n'.join(list_))` instead of this `wb_file.write('\n\n'.join(list_))`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you try with readlines:

```py
#write into the file !
file = open("yourpath", "w")   #w is for write
mylistofstrings = ["line1", "\nline2", "\nline3"]
file.writelines(mylistofstrings)
file.close()
#read the output to check :
file = open("yourpath", "r")   #r is for read
print(file.read())
file.close()
```

Output :

```
line1
line2
line3
```

Warning : if you use "w" for write as done here, it will clear the whole file before writing. If you want to append, just go with "a" for append. Here are all the possible ways to open it:
"r" Open text file for reading.  The stream is positioned at the
  beginning of the file.

"r+" Open for reading and writing.  The stream is positioned at the
 beginning of the file.

"w" Truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing.
 The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

"w+" Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does
 not exist, otherwise it is truncated.  The stream is
 positioned at the beginning of the file.

"a" Open for appending (writing at end of file).  The file is
 created if it does not exist.  The stream is positioned at the
 end of the file.

"a+"     Open for reading and appending (writing at end of file).  The
 file is created if it does not exist.  The initial file
 position for reading is at the beginning of the file, but
 output is always appended to the end of the file.

Tell me if it worked, and if this was useful !

**EDIT : after I saw a comment, just realized : you used / instead of \, so it can't work... BE SURE TO USE \n ! XD**